# .gitignore exclude specific file

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to use `.gitignore` file to exclude `templates.js` located in `public/app/` folder. My `.gitignore` file looks like this:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
composer.phar
composer.lock
.DS_Store
templates.js
```

But when I check in the Git Gui, the `templates.js` file is still show in it. How can I specifically exclude a file using `.gitignore`?

Comment: Does that mean the file is already added to the repository before? `.gitignore` only ignores content to be added.

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes, it has been added to repository before. So, how can I exclude it right now? Is my way of doing in `.gitignore` correct?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

In contrast to what the name "ignore" might suggest. `.gitignore` is only consulted when you `git add` files: in other words a file already added to the (index of the) repository will not be excluded based on the `.gitignore`.

First you better modify the `.gitignore` such that the file is no longer added. Add the following line to the `.gitignore` file:

```
public/app/template.js
```

Next you need to exclude the file from the repository. Probably you **don't want to remove the file** from your file system, this can be done with:

```
git rm --cached public/app/template.js
```

The `--cached` flag ensures the file will not be removed from your file system. (If not important, you can use `git rm public/app/template.js`, **but this will remove the file**).

## Background

The reason `.gitignore` is not proactively used is because you sometimes might want to override the `.gitignore`. Say for instance you don't want to track `*.log` files, you can specify `*.log` in the `.gitignore`. But if there is a specific one you want to track you can add `git add -f some.log`. The `-f` flag forces `git` to add the file.

Comment: a life saver, had my credentials open to the public

Comment: @mLstudent33 I am no expert in git but just wanted to raise the concern that your credentials might still exist in previous versions in that repo. I may be wrong or you have already done something about it - just trying to help, with the little that I can! :)

Comment: @DraxDomax: yes, you can do a "history rewrite": to remove the file over all commits: https://andrewlock.net/rewriting-git-history-simply-with-git-filter-repo/

Answer (score 32):

Once a file has been 'added' to the git repository once, it will continue to be tracked regardless of whether or not it is listed in the .gitignore file.

I'm guessing you added the template.js file previously, in which case it will continue to have changes tracked, until you remove it from the repository.  Once the file has been removed from the repository, it will be properly ignored via the .gitignore file.

The way to remove a file from a git repository (command-line) without deleting it is

```
git rm --cached FILENAME
```

Then once you do that and try to commit with the file in your gitignore, it won't do it.

Note that if you specifically add a file that you have in your gitignore, your manual adding of the file will override the gitignore.

Answer (score 20):

If you are already tracking a file (`git add` on it and `git commit`), `.gitignore` will not help.

I believe what you want is to stop tracking a file, and *then* use `.gitignore` to exclude it. To stop tracking a file but keep the file, use:

`git rm --cached <file>`

Comment: didn't dv, but I think you perhaps should select your words better. *keep it in the repository* is a bit in contrast with *keep it on your local file system*. A repository does not *map* on a filesystem...

Comment: @CommuSoft Fixed to some satisfaction, I wasn't too careful because other people have answered it better.
Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 11):

In this case you can stop tracking `templates.js` with

```
git rm --cached public/app/templates.js
```

As others have explained, `.gitignore` only ignores content to be added. For example, if you frequently use `git add .` and have `templates.js` in your `.gitignore`, then git will not add it.