# Gitignore (Exclude distinct)

Tags: git, gitignore

it´s possible create a directive in the .gitignore file who exclude files distinct a specific file?

I´m trying to make this line but not found the way...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by directive? If you want to exclude a specific file, add it to the .gitignore file... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227858/gitignore-exclude-specific-file

Comment: Hello :) I need to exclude all files distinct a especific file, i don´t know if it´s possible...

Comment: You would like to exclude all files _except_ a specific file?

Comment: Thats the solution! Thanks!