# Branch is being created without add

Tags: git

Im wanting to create a fresh branch for my repository since I'm having previous problems.

However nothing I'm trying is working. When I run 
`(venv) C:\..\..\PycharmProjects\WebP1\DEMOPROJECT>git ls-tree --name-only hope` 
on creation of a new branch, I get

```
.gitignore
DEMOAPP
DEMOPROJECT
__init__.py
__pycache__
db.sqlite3
manage.py
media
static
```

This isnt what i want as i want gitignore to ignore this

```
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
__pycache__/
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
media
```

I have tried `--orphan` branch but it seems to always take me back to a bad commit I don't want anymore. DEMOPROJECT folder is also being made a submodular for some reason which I don't want to happen. 
How can i fix this please? Is there a certain `add` I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Gabriel said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995536/1256452), you create a new branch from an existing commit, so it's going to start with the contents of the existing commit.  You're trying `git checkout --orphan` to avoid starting from an existing commit, and this *is* a valid and sometimes sensible thing to do, but it's probably not what you want.  It's failing because even then, you're starting with an existing *index and work-tree*.

(We can address this:

> DEMOPROJECT folder is also being made a submodule for some reason which I don't want to happen.

later, although a separate question is more appropriate.  And, if you already know the next few sections, you can jump down to the one about the index.)

#### What matters to Git are commits

If you're going to use Git, you need to get used to Git's little quirks.  One of these is that *branches*—or more precisely, *branch names*—aren't all that important to Git.  What matters are *commits*.  It's crucial to learn exactly what a commit does and represents first, and *then* introduce branch names.

Each commit holds a snapshot of some set of files.  That part's pretty straightforward.  The snapshot is what shows up in your `git ls-tree` output—though technically `git ls-tree` has summarized entire sub-trees' files here; you'd need `git ls-tree -r` to see all the files in the snapshot.

A commit *also* holds some metadata: the name and email address of the person who created the commit, for instance, and a date-and-time stamp.  (In fact, there are two of these.)  It holds a log message, which you supply when you make the commit: you should put in something that tells future-you *why* you made this commit.  And—very importantly—each commit holds some number of *parent commit hash IDs* (usually just one).

Each commit, once made, has a unique hash ID.  Every Git in the universe<sup>1</sup> also *agrees* that *that* commit gets *that* hash ID, and no other commit ever gets *that* hash ID.  Once the hash ID is assigned, nothing in the commit can ever change.  (The reason for this is that this hash ID is actually a cryptographic checksum of the commit object's contents.  That's *how* every Git in the universe is able to agree that *this* commit gets *this* hash ID.)

You've seen these hash IDs: they are big ugly strings like `745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26`.  They're not useful to humans, but they are useful to Git.  Git uses the hash ID to find the actual commit, from which it finds the files, and so on.

The stored *parent* hash ID in a commit lets Git find the commit that comes *before* this particular commit.  That is, given a series of commits with random-looking hash IDs, we might draw them with single uppercase letters standing in for the real hash IDs, and we could draw them like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit.  It stores the hash ID of an earlier commit `G`, so Git can load up commit `G`.  If Git does load it up, `G` stores the hash ID of an earlier commit `F`, and so on.  We say that `H` *points to* `G`, `G` points to `F`, and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, this is limited to every Git that *exchanges* this commit with another Git.  If two Git repositories never meet, they can use the same hash ID for different commits.  The chance that they will is tiny: one in 2<sup>160</sup> at the moment.  But if two Git repositories *do* meet and exchange commits—as they will if you `git push` your commits to, say, GitHub—they won't re-use hash IDs: each one will be unique to each commit.

---

#### A branch name points to one commit

This is where branch names come in.  A branch name like `master` simply holds *one* hash ID.  We make sure that it holds the *latest* hash ID, so that `master` points to `H`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

Unlike the commits themselves, the *names* **can** be changed.  To make a new commit, we have Git write out the commit's contents—the snapshot of all files, the log message, your name from `git config --get user.name`, and so on, setting the new commit's parent hash to `H`.  The result is some new unique hash ID that we'll just call `I`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

Now that `I` exists, Git simply writes *its* hash ID into the name `master`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

and now `I` is the last commit in the branch.  (And now we can just draw this as a straight line, with `I` pointing back to `H`.  Note that we didn't change `H` at all: we just added `I`, pointing back to existing `H`.)

This is how branches grow: we have Git add a *new* commit.  Git writes out a snapshot, plus the metadata.  The parent of the new commit is the *current* commit—the one we have checked out.  The new commit gets a new, unique hash ID.  As the last step of the commit operation, Git writes the new hash ID *into* some branch name—the branch we have checked out.

Note that when we make the very first commit, we have *no* existing commit.  So the parent of the *first* commit just doesn't exist.  This new commit has *no* parents; Git calls this a *root commit*.  That gets us the first commit in the repository, so that the name `master` can exist too:

```
A   <-- master
```

After that, the *next* commit `B` will have `A` as its parent, and Git will write `B` into the name `master`.

This is also how `git checkout --orphan` works.  What it does is set things up so that the *next* commit you make will use whatever contents it will use as usual, but have *no parent:* it will be a root commit.  So if you have:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master
```

and do:

```
git checkout --orphan newbranch
git commit
```

you get:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master

I   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

(Whenever we have more than one branch, it's useful to attach the special name `HEAD` to exactly one branch, so that we can see which one is the *current* branch.)

The thing is, this new commit `I` stores the same *snapshot* as existing commit `H`, unless you alter the snapshot-to-be-stored.

#### The index is the source of each new snapshot

Git of course has commits, which are frozen forever.  The files inside a commit are stored in a special, compressed, read-only, Git-only format.  I like to refer to these files as "freeze-dried".  That's great for archival, but completely useless for getting any *new* work done.

Git therefore has the ability to *extract* the files from a commit into a work area.  This work area, called your *working tree* or *work-tree* or some variant on these names, has ordinary files and folders/directories, in your computer's ordinary format.  This allows you to work with them.  It's where you do your work.

You *can* have files in the work-tree that you don't want to put into your *next* commit.  But where *is* your next commit?  Some version control systems say that your work-tree is your next commit.  This is pretty straightforward and easy to use, so it's not what Git does. :-)

Instead, in Git, your *next* commit is stored in something that Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.  These three names all cover one thing.  What's in the index is *all of the files that will go into the next commit*.  These files are in that freeze-dried form, ready to be committed, but unlike committed files, you *can* replace them with new and different files, or even remove them entirely.

You can't see the index directly.  Well, you *can*, but it's kind of awkward.  If you only have a few files, run `git ls-files --stage` to see what's in the index.  If you have a lot of files, this will produce a lot of output!  Here's a snippet from the Git repository for Git itself:

```
100644 6e69877f25791632d98bf7b109a2eaebd04c96af 0       ws.c
100644 9f6c65a5809754717f8c51f809eae78f435bcd12 0       wt-status.c
100644 77dad5b92048851c622a35d8b34d802fbd0ecac6 0       wt-status.h
100644 8509f9ea223a1282a367874c3e3a3ef0c351a30f 0       xdiff-interface.c
100644 ede4246bbd3397086f90217539a2d07a35a4b986 0       xdiff-interface.h
100644 032e3a9f41a2f79eaab78ae36666b8b6218b3899 0       xdiff/xdiff.h
100644 1f1f4a3c7808435f73b0ffd1c35d5b0572516b6c 0       xdiff/xdiffi.c
```

Note that there are no directories/folders in this output.  That's because Git doesn't *store* directories.  It just stores files.  Git simply *makes* a directory / folder if needed to hold a file.  For instance, `xdiff/xdiff.h` is *the* file to Git, but to your computer, the file is named `xdiff.h` inside a folder named `xdiff`.  So Git will make `xdiff` first, if it has to, to write Git's file `xdiff/xdiff.h` to your computer's `xdiff.h`-within-`xdiff`.

#### A *tracked file* is a file that is in the index

Suppose you have, in your work-tree, a file named `main.pyc`.  If this file is *also* in the index, then `main.pyc` is *tracked*.  If this file is *not* in the index, the file is *untracked*.

When you `git checkout` some commit, Git copies all the files from the commit into the index, and then into your work-tree.  When you `git checkout` some *other* commit, Git switches all the index and work-tree files as appropriate.

You can, at any time, run `git add` on a work-tree file.  That copies the work-tree file to the index.  If it was there before, it's been replaced.  If it wasn't there before, it's been added.

You can also, at any time, run `git rm` on any file name.  That removes the index copy *and* the work-tree copy.

And, of course, you can run `git commit`.  Whenever you do, Git packages up whatever is in the index *right now* and uses that to make the new commit.  The new commit's parent is the *current* commit—the one you checked out when you started.  The new commit becomes the *last* commit in the current branch (the one you checked out).

#### The `.gitignore` file can only ignore untracked files

If a file is *tracked*—which, remember, means it's in the index right now—listing that file in `.gitignore` has no effect.

Hence, if you want *not* to commit a file, but it's already in the index, you have to remove it from the index:

```
git rm --cached file
```

The `--cached` option tells Git that even though it's removing the file from the index, it should leave the work-tree copy alone.  The *next* commit thus won't have the file as it has, right after the removal, become untracked.

There's a catch, though: if this commit connects back to some earlier commit, and you ever check out the *earlier* commit, that will write the file into both the index and your work-tree.  Then, when you switch back to this new commit you make that *doesn't* have the file, Git will *remove* the file from the index *and from your work-tree*.

Note that if you're using `--orphan` to make a new branch whose initial commit has *no* previous commit, that can help.  However, the *old* branch still exists, and still has commits that have the file.

#### Conclusion (before we leap into submodules)

You *might* want `--orphan`, but if you really do want it, perhaps you just want to start with a whole new Git repository.

In any case, if you want files to be untracked in future commits, you must remove them from the index if they're in the index now.  You can use `git rm`, which removes them from the index *and* from your work-tree; or you can use `git rm --cached`, which removes them from the index but not from your work-tree.

Once the files are untracked, you can list them in `.gitignore` to make sure they don't get added *to* the index in the future, even though they're in your work-tree.  This also stops `git status` from whining about the untracked files.  Just beware that checking out any older commit that *does* have the file, will put that into the index, for the duration of that checkout.  Switching back to a newer commit that *doesn't* have the file will then *remove* the file from the index **and from your work-tree**.  Be sure that this is OK, or else be very careful when looking at old commits.

#### Submodules

I'm only going to touch on this lightly, because submodules can get pretty complicated.

The stuff that's *not* the work-tree, in a Git repository, is normally all hidden away inside a directory/folder named `.git` at the top level of your work-tree.

If some sub-directory / sub-folder of your work-tree has a `.git` directory, your Git will assume that *some other Git* is controlling that part of your tree.  Your Git will then decide that it shouldn't source-control any of that.  Instead, your Git will add a reference to a commit in that other Git's repository.  This reference takes the form of a *gitlink* in the index.  If you use `git ls-files --stage`, you can see this as a "file" with `mode 160000` (gitlink).

To make Git *not* do that, make sure none of your work-tree is its own repository: that no sub-folder has a `.git` folder inside it.  When using submodules, Git will migrate the `.git` folder into the superproject's `.git` folder, replacing it with a file named `.git` whose contents are the path to the superproject's `.git`, so if a sub-folder has a `.git` *file*, this too can trigger the submodule code.

Comment: I got my project working thank you so much! My ignore file works.My submodule folder is no longer a submodule. my project has all the code online that it needs! It only took me 5 days to get working lol

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to completely understand your question.

A newly created branch is always going to start from a commit you have an other branch. By default, it will start from the last commit on the checked out branch (= the branch you are on when you create the new branch). If you want to specify a commit the newly created branch should start from, so as to ignore the last commit(s) on the checked out branch when creating the branch, you can use `git branch <new_branch_name> <SHA_ID_of_the_commit_you_want_the_branch_to_start_from>`.

if you want to set up `.gitignore` to ignore some files that will not be added, you need to edit it to obtain that behavior. You can specify these file names, along with the path to these files, in the `.gitignore` file. This [Stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227858/gitignore-exclude-specific-file) expands on it.

Comment: Yeah just realised i was asking two questions in one really. Asking about branches and why they dont change... Prior knowledge had me led to believe they did every time you made a new branch. Second one I thought was because of this with why my folder was a submodule. Although Torek has explained both excellently. Also I was thinking .gitignore would have something to do with a coulpe of those files which i thought making a new branch would affect. Thanks for your help though @Gabriel!